# how to reduced padding for `li` in `select2` using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used `select2` library and trying to change `li` padding using jquery.
Example:

```
$('#selectField').on('select2:open', function (e) { $('ul.select2-results__options li').css('padding',  '4px');
});
```

but above code is not working.

Comment: why are you trying it using scripting? Let the CSS do this.

Comment: Because multiple times to use dropdown in same page but change only under header section dropdown that's way i will try using jquery.

Comment: Then you will find specific `ul` id  as `#select2-selectField-results`. Please find my updated answer below.

Comment: @Sneha: that because you dont get the right selector. both tanmay comment is your clue

Comment: @plonknimbuzz thanks but  i will already try using css but problem css apply to all select2 and i should try apply only one dropdown not all

Comment: @SnehaPatel my answer is same. that because you cant get the right selector. try to create fiddle i will show you

Answer (score 1):

Try it using CSS

```
 ul.select2-results__options li {
       padding :4px
    }
```

for specific Dropdown, in your case #selectField

```
#select2-selectField-results li {
           padding :4px
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
$('#selectField').on('select2:open', function (e) {
  $('ul.select2-results__options > li').css('padding',  '4px');
});
```

I have added a `>` in the CSS selector since the `li` elements are child elements of the `ul.select2-results__options`.

If you prefer plain CSS, use the CSS below instead of the jQuery above.

```
ul.select2-results__options > li {
  padding: 4px;
}
```